# How to output and filter collection using "->where" filter?

Tags: database, collection, model, filter

[image]

[image]

I trying to get output from collection using 'where'
filter but no result.
This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('my_work/datanews')
            ->getCollection()
            ->getSelect()
            ->where('menu_id = ?', '1');

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            echo $item->getData('collection');
        }
```

What are the problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('my_work/datanews')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('menu_id', 1);

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        echo $item->getData('content');
    }
```

Note: If column `collection` exists on your collection, you should be able to use `$item->getData('collection')` as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Equals: eq**
This is the default operator and does not need to be specified. Below you can see how to use the operator, but also how to skip it and just enter the value you're using.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('menu_id', array('eq' => 1)); // Using the operator
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('menu_id', 1); // Without using the operator
```

[Learn More about Attribute filter condition](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)